# SQL71578 error with Azure SQL Database

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

I've got a Windows Form Application using an Azure SQL server as datasource. Everything worked fine until I added a new column to one of my tables. The type of this column is bit. Since then I get the same error to all of my tables, however this does not prevent me from starting the application in debug mode.

> SQL71578: The element Table: [dbo].[Fogyasztok] has property
>   Durability set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL
>   Database v12.

This is a sample error message of 'Fogyasztok' table.

I looked for this issue but didn't find anything meaningful or useful. I'm wondering what this issue really is, please help me to find out.

Many thanks!

Comment: From the error message it looks like you have set Durability on this table to be enabled. Is this the case? Additionally if you connect to your database and run " sp_help '[dbo].[Fogyasztok]' " and share the output, and share the DDL you used to alter the table, I will be able to provide you a better answer.

Comment: The result of sp_help: [Result file](http://1drv.ms/1zOYEI2)

Comment: Is this the table where you added the column or just one of the tables having the issue?

Comment: This is just one of the tables. [This](http://1drv.ms/1GpI3Ck) is the "guilty" one.

Comment: [Delayed Durability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449490.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a setting for [In-Memory Optimization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx) for a database. Try to connect to the master db on the server and run  "ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabaseName] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = Disabled". This will force delayed durability to the default setting.